# Checkbox or dropdown in select using twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently designing an advanced search form, and on two select drop down items I'm letting the user set a check box. Example: The user can, after checking the check box let the search start from year 2000. With the check box unchecked, the search is restricted to the selected year.

Now with bootstrap the check box got a bit big, and so I've played with a drop-down left to the select box - using divs and group button classes.

I'm now asking anyone here if there are any better options for me, and/or if you have examples on how others have done this that you like.

An example on bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/89400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to set the selected text in the button..

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/89851

Is that what you're looking for?